# Authentification using API

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I've worked on several websites few years ago and I want to be up-to-date with "the new web" so I'm working on a website using Laravel and Lumen to practice.

I have an architecture like that:

- An API using Lumen (with databases: users data, user preferences, …)
- A website (without database, this part just ask to the API some data and allow the user to be connected to his account)

Currently everything in my API is public: retrieving users, deleting accounts, searching users, etc.

The problem is that I don't know how to allow situations like that:

- Allow my website to execute actions calling the API (call private routes on my API)
- I would like to have some routes public on my API (the easiest part, it's done actually)
- I would like to allow external users to call my API if they have a valid token (Google analytics, Bugsnag like services)

I'm thinking about services like Google analytics, Bugsnag, …: this services ask the user to put a token/key in Javascript. Is it a problem if someone take the token and use it on his personal website and/or in a mobile application?

I've read about o-auth 2, is it the place to start?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try for:

> 1. Allow my website to execute actions calling the API (call private routes on my API)

- **JWT** **Authentification** (JSON Web Tokens).

*How do JSON Web Tokens work?*

In authentication, when the user successfully logs in using his credentials, a JSON Web Token will be returned and must be saved locally (typically in local storage, but cookies can be also used), instead of the traditional approach of creating a session in the server and returning a cookie. Read more [about jwt](https://jwt.io/introduction/)

Use this [JWT-AUTH](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) for connection jwt mechanism with lumen/laravel.

> 2. I would like to allow external users to call my API if they have a
>      valid token (Google analytics, Bugsnag like services)

For that task I suggest you to use OAuth 2.0 protocol